# Separating Data Access Layer from Business Logic Layer .Net Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, architecture, .net-core-3.1

I currently have a .NET Core 3.1 Web Application that contains an Entity Framework *DBContext* class. At run time startup.cs, fetches the connection string and injects the *DBContext* into the *repository* class I need it in. I need to move the *repository* and the *DBContext* into their own project within the Solution so that the web application can continue to use as well as another Console App project in the Solution (which will run as a regular back end service on our server).

My Qs are

1. How do I inject the *DBContext* (with the correct connection string) and the *repository* into the Web App and the Console App?
2. Is this (Q1) possible or do I just have to call up an instance without using dependency injection?
3. How can DBContext get its connection string without startup.cs?

Answer (score 0):

One of the options could be to add an expansion method in your module like this:

```
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMyModule(this IServiceCollection services, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> dbSetupAction, IConfiguration config = null)
        {
           //Add all services (Dependency injections)    
            return services;
        }
    }
```

and then you can call it inside your main StartUp

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
....
ervices.AddMyModule(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("AppName")), Configuration.GetSection("MyModuleName"));
...
}
```

And of course you would have to reference your module project from your main project (where the Startup is located)

Comment: I see, so you're suggested I created on dependency injection container, then call this from every project that needs the injected services?

Comment: Yes. I believe it is a nice way to do it.